# How to refresh ProxyModel and tableview with Pushbutton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

Below is the example code.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql, uic


class FilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._filter_value = None

    @property
    def filter_value(self):
        return self._filter_value

    @filter_value.setter
    def filter_value(self, value):
        self._filter_value = value
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        if self.filter_value is None:
            return super().filterAcceptsRow(sourceRow, sourceParent)
        if self.filterKeyColumn() >= 0:
            value = (
                self.sourceModel()
                .index(sourceRow, self.filterKeyColumn(), sourceParent)
                .data(self.filterRole())
            )
            return value == self.filter_value

        for column in range(self.columnCount()):
            value = (
                self.sourceModel()
                .index(sourceRow, column, sourceParent)
                .data(self.filterRole())
            )
            if value == self.filter_value:
                return True
        return False

    def setFilterRegExp(self, filter):
        self.filter_value = None
        super().setFilterRegExp(filter)


class UI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("tableview.ui", self)
        self.tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        db.setDatabaseName("book.db")
        db.open()

        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("card")
        self.model.select()

        self.proxy = FilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.tableView.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.model.select()


        self.refresh.clicked.connect(self.refresh_table)

        r = self.model.record()
        column_names = [r.field(i).name().title() for i in range(r.count())]

        self.comboBox.addItems([x for x in column_names])

        self.horizontalHeader = self.tableView.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(
            self.tableView_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked
        )
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.lineEdit_textChanged)

    def tableView_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)

        values = []

        for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            value = self.model.index(row, logicalIndex).data(self.proxy.filterRole())
            values.append(value)

        action_all = QtWidgets.QAction("All", self)
        action_all.setData(None)
        menu.addAction(action_all)
        menu.addSeparator()

        for value in sorted(list(set(values))):
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(str(value), self)
            action.setData(value)
            menu.addAction(action)

        headerPos = self.tableView.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())
        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(logicalIndex)

        action = menu.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

        if action is not None:
            self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(logicalIndex)
            self.proxy.filter_value = action.data()

    def lineEdit_textChanged(self):
        search = QtCore.QRegExp(
            self.lineEdit.text(), QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive, QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
        )
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(self.comboBox.currentIndex())
        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)



    def refresh_table(self):
        print("refresh")
        


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = UI()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

I am using FilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel), QTableView and QtSql.QSqlTableModel. I am able to filter rows. My question is How to refresh the proxymodel or tableview to show all rows with push button. As per above image the rows was filtered with qmenu. Now i want to refresh and show the all rows after clicked With the Qpushbutton, I want to show all rows with  Not only with the menu option but also with the Qpushbutton. Is it possible to refresh, How to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the filter then you must set None to filter_value:

```
def refresh_table(self):
    self.proxy.filter_value = None
```